# Pytorch reports CUDA version mismatches

Tags: python, pytorch

I have both 11.8 and 12.0 CUDA version. But when I run the code, there comes the following error:

```
RuntimeError:
The detected CUDA version (12.0) mismatches the version that was used to compile
PyTorch (11.8). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.
```

How can I solve it??

I have checked if CUDA 11.8 successfully installed using cmd command, and it turned out to be ok. Also, the system path is correctly set.

Comment: Try uninstaling cuda version 12.0. Or when running the code specify to use the 11.8 version. I think thau fisrts option is the best

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple CUDA versions installed, assuming that the newer one (12.0) is a default one. And you need to run a script that depends on old CUDA (11.8) version, simply set/update the following env vars before starting your python script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.8
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin

python my_py-cuda118_script.py
```